# What is the dIfference between c# static and non-static methods?

Tags: c#, overloading

In this code, is there a difference between the static function and the non-static one?

And, beside the fact that a static function belongs to the object and not to the instance, are there more differences?

```
public class ClassName
{
   public void f1(SomeObject n)
   {
      n.someProperty = 1;
   }
   public static void f1(ref SomeObject n)
   {
      n.someProperty = 1;
   }
}
```

duplicate?
Yes, so it seems. just note that in the other question there were no answers that addressed the question itself.

Comment: No, there is no other differences hence for non-static method call you need to create `ClassName` instance.

Comment: This code won't even compile. You can't overload a method solely on instance/static.

Comment: @rossipedia I don't think the example code was meant to compile, but yes, you are right

Comment: changed it, tho @Jcl is correct.

Comment: result is the same but best practice is to use a static call. there are 3 advantages:   1.  memory footprint reduction as mentioned by JCL, 2.  More intuivite since there is no ambiguity about setting up the state first by calling other methods, 3.  Much easier to Unit Test (basically because of reason 2).

Comment: #1 is incorrect. The instance method doesn't affect runtime size at all.

Comment: SomeObject is passed by ref. So, if it is holding reference to shared resource then use locks before modifying it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except those that you already mention: no, there's no difference. In fact, functions that don't really affect (or require to know the status of) an instance of the same object, should be preferred static (that would, at the very least, reduce the memory footprint of every instance of the object).

### Update

Now that I think of it, I don't think it'd really affect the memory footprint. So go with what looks better, "design-wise"

Just adding, that if a method (as mentioned) doesn't need the instance of an object, "design-wise", it should be better as static. If anything, because you don't have to instantiate an object to use it.

Comment: You are correct. Methods/Functions don't add to runtime size of an instance at all.

Comment: @rossipedia that's right, it took me a couple minutes to think about it. Fields would, but not methods.

Answer (score -1):

Why have `f1` associated with `ClassName`.  You should [extend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb383977.aspx) `SomeObject`.

```
public static class SomeObjectExtensions
{
   public static void f1(this SomeObject o) { o.SomeProperty = 1; }
}
```

Then your code can do:

```
var so = new SomeObject();
so.f1();
```

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the OP's question

Comment: @rossipedia, Agree with you.  OP should reconsider the approach s/he is taking.

Comment: My point is we don't even know if he's taking "an approach". The way the question is asked seems like pure theory/curiosity.

Answer (score -1):

Judging only by the lines you've posted in the question you should definitely use 
the static version because calling an instance method has it's performance penalties:

1.) Calling an instance method behind involves loading the instance on the evaluation which is the "this" argument, which is avoided
        calling a static method.

2.) Calling an instance method compiles to the "Callvirt" IL opcode that   performs a null check for the "this" first passed argument and
    then tries to resolve the calling runtime actual instance method,
    this applies to all instance methods, not only for the virtual ones
    as the name might wrongly imply. Calling a static methods on the
    other hand will compile to the "call" IL opcode which will just call
    the method.

3.) Static methods are stateless by their nature which makes it easier for multithreaded design ( in case they do use an external shared static field).

Comment: "1.) The IL for an instance method is generated for each instance created, and static method's IL is generated only once." This is **absolutely** incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'll look in to that more thoroughly.
 Currently i removed it from the answer.